# Sharing APs, but different gateways

Tags: routing, wireless-networking, vlan, vpn

I'm moving into a student apartment building with three friends soon, and I could use some help in designing the network.

The situation is as follows. We each have our own outgoing connection with a static IP. There's a socket in the wall that one can just hook a patch cable onto. Each of these connections is registered to one of us, and everyone is responsible for the traffic that passes out from their IP. The obvious thing to do here is hook up a router to your own connection and create a personal LAN and access point.

As we walk around the common rooms of the flat, however, staying connected to our own access points is not as reliable as one might want. Walls, distance and interference are in the way. There's always one of the other access points in close range, though.

Idealy, I'm looking for a solution where we roam amongst eachother's access points, but the outgoing traffic is sent out via everyone's personal connection. Additionally, I'd very much prefer not to link the devices via physical cables, but instead use their public IP addresses and pass the traffic through 'along the outside' - drawing cables is a bit of a hassle, seeing as we cannot drill through the walls. Each of the outgoing connections is likely hooked up to a switch somewhere in the building using gigabit, although I'm not certain of that yet.

If there's really no proper other solution, I suppose installing a fifth access point and drawing cables from the devices to that instead (i.e. a 'spider in the web') is something I can concede to, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: The type of hardware that would allow you to do this is a several factors more expensive then simply buying a better home router with better range.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that? What are you suggesting?

Comment: Elaborate on what exactly?  The hardware required to do what you describe is several times more expensive then a good 801.11ac router which likely provide you with the required range.  Attempting to not only merge 3 different separate connections but seamlessly merge 3 different access points isn't a small task.

Comment: One thought I had while reading, is before you do anything with the setup use a tool like [MetaGeek's inSSIDer](http://www.inssider.com/) to set sensible wireless channels for each AP. Stick with [channels 1,6,and 11](http://www.metageek.net/support/why-channels-1-6-and-11/) for best results especially since your AP's are in close physical proximity.